# Can I pass environment variables to a Docker container using Cockpit?

Tags: docker, cockpit

I don't see such an option in the UI:

[image: Cockpit's Run Image dialog box].

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [comment by a Cockpit developer](https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/issues/3271), the UI doesn't currenly expose the ability to specify environment variables when starting a container.

The recommended approach is to simply run `docker run` from the command line and [pass the environment variables in the traditional way](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables), thus bypassing Cockpit's Run Image dialog:

```
docker run -e "MYENV=24" myimage
```

Once created, the resulting container can still be monitored and managed from Cockpit.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably pass it in the command field

Try `-e MYENV=24` and see if that shows up in the container

Comment: Why is there a down vote without a comment on why it was down voted ? If you let me know what is wrong with the answer, I'll be glad to improve it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify this earlier: your answer is incorrect. The "Command" field in Cockpit doesn't actually parse the -e parameter like the Docker CLI would, it just interprets it as being part of the command that runs inside the container. I appreciate your suggestion, but from my limited understanding of the SO guidelines, it seems like it would have been better off as a comment.